# Powershell - Searching for strings (in list) in a word document

Tags: list, powershell, search, cpu-word

I found some code for searching for strings in a Word Document.  I altered it to suit my needs (I need to search from a very long list of strings).  Unfortunately, I am getting a weird error.

While the script is running, it opens the word document, searches the word document and here is where it gets weird, instead of closing the document and opening the next, it presents me with a 'save as' dialog box and the script hangs until I cancel out of it.  When I cancel out of it, my script continues.

Here is the script I'm using, would anyone see where I'm going south?

```
$results = @{}

Write-Host "Loading getStringMatch into memory" -ForegroundColor DarkMagenta

Function getStringMatch
{
    # Loop through all *.doc files in the $path directory
    Foreach ($file In $files)
    {
        Write-Host "Searching In  ... $($File.FullName) " -ForegroundColor DarkYellow
        $document = $application.documents.open($file.FullName,$false,$true)

        $range = $document.content

        If($range.Text -match ".{$($charactersAround)}$($findtext).{$($charactersAround)}"){
             $properties = @{
                File = $file.FullName
                Match = $findtext
                TextAround = $Matches[0] 
             }
             $results += @(New-Object -TypeName PsCustomObject -Property $properties)
        }

        $document.close()
        Write-Host "Closing Document  ... $($File.FullName) " -ForegroundColor Red
    }

    #If($results){
    #    $results | Export-Csv $output -NoTypeInformation
    #}
    $application.quit()
}
    
$searchWords=Get-Content "C:\Temp\USDA_Search_For.txt"
Foreach ($sw in $searchWords)
{
    Write-Host "Setting Variables ..." -ForegroundColor DarkMagenta
    Set-StrictMode -Version latest
    $path     = "C:\Temp"
    $files    = Get-Childitem $path -Include *.docx,*.doc -Recurse | Where-Object { !($_.psiscontainer) }
    $output   = "C:\Temp\Found.csv"
    $application = New-Object -comobject word.application
    $application.visible = $False
    $findtext = "First"
    $charactersAround = 30
    #$results = @{}


    $findtext = $sw
    Write-Host "Searching For ... $findtext" -ForegroundColor Green
    getStringMatch

   #clean up stuff
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($application) | Out-Null
    Remove-Variable -Name application
    [gc]::collect()
    [gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
    
    }
    If($results){
        $results | Export-Csv $output -NoTypeInformation
    }
import-csv $output
```

Comment: Do you get the confirmation prompt before or after it outputs "Closing Document   ... <file path>" to the screen? If before, try changing `$document.close()` to `$document.Close($false)`

Comment: Also, define the `$application = New-Object -comobject word.application` **above** the foreach loop (just once). Remove `$application.quit()` from the `getStringMatch` function and move it to **below** the foreach loop. After that do the clean up stuff to release the COM objects from memory

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen and Theo
That worked!!  Thank you both.

I have another question if I may.  I think I may have coded this wrong.  I'm opening and closing 100+ Word Docs for each string I'm looking for.  
Is there a way I could alter the code above to open each Word Doc just once and search for every string then move onto the next Word Doc? 
The reason I ask, is my test folder of 25 Docs and 150+ strings to search for takes over 5 minutes to complete.

Comment: You could combine all `$searchWords` with a regex OR `|` so you wouldn't need to loop those at all.. `$searchWords= '({0})' -f ((Get-Content "C:\Temp\USDA_Search_For.txt | ForEach-Object { [regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|')`

Comment: @Theo

That worked a Charm!!!  It's blazing fast now.
Thank you very much!!